# Not sure why textbox isn't showing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a simple browser with a search box in PyQt5. This is what I've written:

```py
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
class App(QMainWindow):
        def initiate(self):
                super().initiate()
                self.InitUI()
        def initUI(self):
                self.setWindowTitle('Browser')
                self.setGeometry(100, 200, 1000, 2000)
                self.searchbox = QLineEdit(self)
                self.searchbox.move(20, 20)
                self.searchbox.resize(1500,40)
                self.go = QPushButton('Go', self)
                self.go.move(1810, 20)
                self.go.connect(self.gourl)
                self.show()
        def gourl(self):
                url = self.searchbox.text()

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Loading...')
        self.titleChanged.connect(self.adjustTitle)

    def load(self,url):
        self.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        App.searchbox.setText(url)

    def adjustTitle(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = Browser()
box = App()
box.show()
view.show()
view.load("https://duckduckgo.com")
app.exec_()
```

The browser part loads, but the textbox doesn't show. Python also throws this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\browser.py", line 43, in <module>
    view.load("https://duckduckgo.com")
  File "C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\browser.py", line 34, in load
    App.searchbox.setText(url)
AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'searchbox'
```

I don't know why the textbox doesn't show, and I can't understand why the error is being thrown. Can someone please point out the error?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hi there! The error `type object 'App' has no attribute 'searchbox'` is just saying that you don't have inside the `__init__()` method the attribute `searchbox`. Try create the method `__init__` and add the attribute `searchbox`, so you can call it in the main class and even in other class that extents the main class.

Comment: @Tuna Sorry, that doesn't work. Still getting the same error. Thanks, though!

Comment: Great! The Browser class doesn't extends the App class, try this: `class Browser (App, QWebView)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's New in Qt 5.6
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew56.html#removed-functionality
>
> Porting from QtWebKit to QtWebEngine
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

```
import sys
#import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QMainWindow

#from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
#from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

#from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
#from optparse import OptionParser


class App(QMainWindow):
#    def initiate(self):
#        super().initiate()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()                         # - InitUI ->  + initUI

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Browser')
        self.setGeometry(100, 200, 500, 400)
        self.searchbox = QLineEdit("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841281/not-sure-why-textbox-isnt-showing", self)
        self.searchbox.move(20, 20)
        self.searchbox.resize(460,40)
        self.go = QPushButton('Go', self)
        self.go.move(370, 100)
        self.go.clicked.connect(self.gourl)      # clicked
        self.show()

    def gourl(self):
        url = self.searchbox.text()
        print(f"url = {url}")

        self.webview = Browser()
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

        self.webview.show()


class Browser(QWebEngineView):   #(QWebView):
    windowList = []

    def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):
        new_webview = Browser()
        new_window  = App()
        new_window.setCentralWidget(new_webview)
        #new_window.show()
        self.windowList.append(new_window)  
        return new_webview


"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
#        self.view = QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Loading...')
        self.titleChanged.connect(self.adjustTitle)
    def load(self,url):
        self.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        App.searchbox.setText(url)
    def adjustTitle(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title())
"""        

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    view = Browser()
    box = App()
    box.show()
#    view.show()
#    view.load("https://duckduckgo.com")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> without a new window?? if possible

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, 
                             QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget   = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.searchbox = QLineEdit("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841281/not-sure-why-textbox-isnt-showing", self)
        self.go = QPushButton('Go', self)
        self.go.clicked.connect(self.gourl)  
        self.webview = Browser()        

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.webview, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.searchbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.go, 1, 1)

    def gourl(self):
        url = self.searchbox.text()
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))


class Browser(QWebEngineView):   #(QWebView):
    windowList = []
    def createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage_WebWindowType):
        new_webview = Browser()
        new_window  = App()
        new_window.setCentralWidget(new_webview)
        #new_window.show()
        self.windowList.append(new_window)  
        return new_webview


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.setWindowTitle('Browser')
    box.resize(600, 500)
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! without a new window?? if possible